# Cant get picture in html file

Tags: javascript, image

Basically what I'm trying to do is when I press a button, an image to appear. Everything works fine when it appears in the body, but when I try to make it appear in some div it tells me its not a function.

```
function profile() {
    var src = "../trunk/Images/Capture.png";
    show_image("../trunk/Images/Capture.png", "Profile");
}


function show_image(src, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var element = document.getElementByClassName("console");
    img.src = src;
    img.alt = alt;
    element.appendChild(img);
}`
```

Here's my code, everything works fine with `document.body.appendChild(img);` but with the way it is now it crashes :(

Comment: whats the error ur getting in the console ??

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function as `document.getElementByClassName()`.  It's `getElementsByClassName()`, with "elements" plural, and it returns a list of matching elements.

If you really only have one element on your page, you can give it an id and use `document.getElementById()`. If you do want to use the class name, then call `.getElementsByClassName()` and then dereference with array notation to find the element reference itself:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("console")[0];
```

(which assumes you want the first matching element).

Comment: Yup that does it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The standard browser DOM doesn't have a `getElementByClassName` method. It has `getElementsByClassName` — plural — which returns an HTML Collection (which is an object like an array which contains all the matching elements).